# Convert log File Data to Json Object in Vue client

Tags: javascript, json, go, logging, vuejs2

I have a log file as follow:

```
{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530","M":"Route.go:74[IN : GetLatestLogs]"}
{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530","M":"Service.go:40[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogService]"}
{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530","M":"DAO.go:117[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogDAO]"}
{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530","M":"DAO.go:148[OUT : GetRecentServerErrorLogDAO]"}
{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530","M":"Service.go:47[OUT : GetRecentServerErrorLogService]"}
{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530","M":"Route.go:79[OUT : GetLatestLogs]"}
{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:40:55.331+0530","M":"Route.go:74[IN : GetLatestLogs]"}
```

I am reading this file in the Golang echo server as follow:

```
file, err := os.Open(logFilePath)

stat, _ := os.Stat(logFilePath)
buf := make([]byte, stat.Size())
_, err = file.Read(buf)
serverLog := string(buf)
```

and return this string generated back

```
return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, serverLog)
```

this is what I get as result

```
"{\"L\":\"DEBUG\",\"T\":\"2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530\",\"M\":\"Route.go:74[IN : GetLatestLogs]\"}\n{\"L\":\"DEBUG\",\"T\":\"2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530\",\"M\":\"Service.go:40[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogService]\"}\n{\"L\":\"DEBUG\",\"T\":\"2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530\",\"M\":\"DAO.go:117[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogDAO]\"}\n{\"L\":\"DEBUG\",\"T\":\"2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530\",\"M\":\"DAO.go:148[OUT : GetRecentServerErrorLogDAO]\"}\n{\"L\":\"DEBUG\",\"T\":\"2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530\",\"M\":\"Service.go:47[OUT : GetRecentServerErrorLogService]\"}\n{\"L\":\"DEBUG\",\"T\":\"2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530\",\"M\":\"Route.go:79[OUT : GetLatestLogs]\"}\n{\"L\":\"DEBUG\",\"T\":\"2021-11-01T17:40:55.331+0530\",\"M\":\"Route.go:74[IN : GetLatestLogs]\"}{\"L\":\"DEBUG\",\"T\":\"2021-11-02T09:48:49.982+0530\",\"M\":\"controlPanelRoute.go:74[IN : GetLatestLogs]\"}\n{\"L\":\"DEBUG\",\"T\":\"2021-11-02T09:48:49.982+0530\",\"M\":\"controlPanelService.go:40[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogService]\"}\n{\"L\":\"DEBUG\",\"T\":\"2021-11-02T09:48:49.982+0530\",\"M\":\"controlPanelDAO.go:117[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogDAO]\"}\n"
```

I want to convert this received response to a JSON object.

This is my desired output:

```
[
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530",
        "M": "Route.go:74[IN : GetLatestLogs]"
    },
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530",
        "M": "Service.go:40[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogService]"
    },
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530",
        "M": "DAO.go:117[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogDAO]"
    },
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530",
        "M": "DAO.go:148[OUT : GetRecentServerErrorLogDAO]"
    },
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530",
        "M": "Service.go:47[OUT : GetRecentServerErrorLogService]"
    },
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530",
        "M": "Route.go:79[OUT : GetLatestLogs]"
    },
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:40:55.331+0530",
        "M": "Route.go:74[IN : GetLatestLogs]"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it seems you depend on Gin to do the conversion for you:

```
return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, serverLog)
```

You can actually handle it yourself, but it may require Unmarshalling line by line, since the log text file isn't a valid JSON array. Then I marshall the valid structure back into JSON. In the example below I used bufio to read the text file by line, and unmarshall to a Log struct:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "bufio"
)

type Log struct {
    L   string
    T   string
    M   string
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("log.txt")
    defer f.Close()

    var logs []Log
    var log Log

    input := bufio.NewScanner(f)

    for input.Scan() {
        textByte := []byte(input.Text())
        err = json.Unmarshal(textByte, &log)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Problems with unmarshalling: %v\n", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        logs = append(logs, log)
    }

    data, err := json.MarshalIndent(logs, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error in marshalling: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", data)
}
```

Or you can return the string from a function:

```
return fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", data)
```

Here's the output:

```
[
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530",
        "M": "Route.go:74[IN : GetLatestLogs]"
    },
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530",
        "M": "Service.go:40[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogService]"
    },
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530",
        "M": "DAO.go:117[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogDAO]"
    },
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530",
        "M": "DAO.go:148[OUT : GetRecentServerErrorLogDAO]"
    },
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530",
        "M": "Service.go:47[OUT : GetRecentServerErrorLogService]"
    },
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530",
        "M": "Route.go:79[OUT : GetLatestLogs]"
    },
    {
        "L": "DEBUG",
        "T": "2021-11-01T17:40:55.331+0530",
        "M": "Route.go:74[IN : GetLatestLogs]"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like one valid Json statement after another.  You can open the file, create a decoder with `json.NewDecoder(filehandle)`, and read one Json statement out if it after another.  Heres' an example with the input hard coded:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "encoding/json"
)

var input =[]byte( `{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530","M":"Route.go:74[IN : GetLatestLogs]"}
{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530","M":"Service.go:40[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogService]"}
{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530","M":"DAO.go:117[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogDAO]"}
{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530","M":"DAO.go:148[OUT : GetRecentServerErrorLogDAO]"}
{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530","M":"Service.go:47[OUT : GetRecentServerErrorLogService]"}
{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530","M":"Route.go:79[OUT : GetLatestLogs]"}
{"L":"DEBUG","T":"2021-11-01T17:40:55.331+0530","M":"Route.go:74[IN : GetLatestLogs]"}`)

func main() {
    r := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBuffer(input))
    var data interface{}
    for i := 0;;i++{
        if err := r.Decode(&data); err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            panic(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%d: %+v\n", i, data)
        }
    }
}
```

Output should be:

```
0: map[L:DEBUG M:Route.go:74[IN : GetLatestLogs] T:2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530]
1: map[L:DEBUG M:Service.go:40[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogService] T:2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530]
2: map[L:DEBUG M:DAO.go:117[IN : GetRecentServerErrorLogDAO] T:2021-11-01T17:37:54.167+0530]
3: map[L:DEBUG M:DAO.go:148[OUT : GetRecentServerErrorLogDAO] T:2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530]
4: map[L:DEBUG M:Service.go:47[OUT : GetRecentServerErrorLogService] T:2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530]
5: map[L:DEBUG M:Route.go:79[OUT : GetLatestLogs] T:2021-11-01T17:37:54.168+0530]
6: map[L:DEBUG M:Route.go:74[IN : GetLatestLogs] T:2021-11-01T17:40:55.331+0530]
```

As you can see, `Decode()`  stops at the end of a Json expression, so you can just keep reading over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

```golang
file, err := os.Open("/log/file/path")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
info, err := file.Stat()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

logs := make(json.RawMessage, 1, info.Size()+1) // len=1 for '['
dec := json.NewDecoder(file)
for dec.More() {
    var log json.RawMessage
    if err := dec.Decode(&log); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    logs = append(logs, log...)
    logs = append(logs, ',')
}
if n := len(logs); n > 1 {
    logs[0], logs[n-1] = '[', ']'
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, logs)
}
```